# How consistent is phase on the National Grid?

Tags: mains, phase

How consistent is phase on the National Grid in the UK? If I have a device plugged into a socket in Scotland and another down in Cornwall, how far out of phase will the two AC sine waves be?

I have a project that needs to filter out AC mains interference, and I'm wondering if I need to measure the phase near to the filter or if I can have one for the entire UK grid.

Comment: What speed does electricity travel at in cables? Can you work out how many degrees of shift there will be based on this number?

Comment: @Andyaka let's say 900km, that would be 3.3ms or about 60°. Can it really be as simple as that I wonder?

Comment: @user if the grid frequency was constant, it'd be that easy; alas, it's not, because frequency variation is the primary method of generation control, so, all Londoners pressing down their toasters in the morning 5min before Glasgow does will lead to the generators in England slowing down a bit more rapidly than in Scotland, and thus, there will be "waves" of frequency variation oscillating through the grid until frequency stabilizes.

Comment: @user I'm sure there's much better introductory material out there, but outside university, this is the only talk I actively remember about grid regulation and frequency: [How to cause a blackout (and why it's not that easy)](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7323-wie_man_einen_blackout_verursacht#l=eng) (which has an english dub, select "eng" from the "gears" menu).

Comment: Use a phase locked loop with a long loop constant to track the nominal phase. Transients and mains signalling like Zellweger shouldn’t affect the recovered phase.